# How to set a default value for a spring-mvc restful url pattern?

Tags: spring-mvc, parameters, restful-url

I have a question here. I use a restful url `@RequestMapping("download/{fileName}/{id}/{count}")` to receive parameter form JSP.As follows：

```
 @RequestMapping("show/{pageNum}/{pageSize}")
public String showFileByPage(@PathVariable int pageNum,@PathVariable int pageSize){

    //do something
}
```

then, i find that i have to access this HandlerMethod by using the complete url like `http://localhost:8080/show/1/2`.

Now, i wanna to use an omitted like `http://localhost:8080/show` to access this page , but it occur an error `404`, error description: `The requested resource is not available`.

Then in this case, how can i correct this error and set default value for pageNum and pageSize like pageNum = 1(default),pageSize = 2(default)

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that.
So i see two answers:
1) Create second RequestMapping with "show" path (without the rest of URL)
2) Create optional parameters (look here: https://www.n-k.de/2016/05/optional-path-variables-with-spring-boot-rest-mvc.html )

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is work and very helpful ! https://www.n-k.de/2016/05/optional-path-variables-with-spring-boot-rest-mvc.html